# Intersection of a countable set with [1, n]

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A \in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$,
for which $\mathbb{P}(A) := \lim_{n -> \infty}\frac{|A \cap [1,n]|}{n}$ exists, and $\mathbb{P}(A) \in \{0,1\}$.

So my question is, isn't it redundant to say $|A \cap [1,n]|$ as well as exists? Couldn't we just have said |A|?
If A is finite then the intersection is still A and the limit will always be 0. If A is infinite, then the limit will always be 1, since A will be countably infinite.

Thank you!

Comment: No.  There are infinite $A$s which doesn't have asymptotic density 1.

Comment: What do you get if $A$ is the set of even integers? Or the set of perfect squares?

Comment: Yeah I don't know how I missed that. For the even integers I'd get $\frac{1}{2}$. I don't know for the perfect square though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if $A$ is infinite, it does not mean the limit is one. For example, consider $A$ only consists of powers of two. Then $\frac{|A\cap [1,n]|}{n} \approx \frac{\log(n)}{n} \to 0$. It's also possible to construct an $A$ where the limit does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I missed that. For some reason I was thinking of cardinality, So since all infinite countable sets have the same cardinal I just assumed the limit would be 1.